# Displaying thumbnails generated from UWP on iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm having an issue with storing a thumbnail image from a video as bytes and then displaying it back to the user. Specifically when the thumbnail has been created from within the UWP platform and I'm then trying to view it from an iOS device, all other platform combinations work fine.

The thumbnail creation within my app has platform specific implementations.

Within UWP I generate the thumbnail from the video using the recommended StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync() and convert it into bytes using the following method:

```
        //rawVideo is type byte[] and will come from the device camera or a file upload
        await __LocalStorage.CreateTemporaryFileAsync(VIDEO_FILENAME, rawVideo);
        StorageFile _StorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync(VIDEO_FILENAME);

        StorageItemThumbnail _Thumbnail = await _StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.VideosView);
        byte[] _Bytes = new byte[_Thumbnail.Size];

        using (Stream _Stream = _Thumbnail.AsStream())
        {
            using (MemoryStream _MemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                _Stream.CopyTo(_MemoryStream);
                _Bytes = _MemoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

That byte array is then stored on a model to be used elsewhere in the app. I then have a BindingConverter within my shared code that will take this byte array and display it as an image within other pages:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource _ImageSource = null;
        if (value != null && value is byte[] _ImageBytes)
        {
            _ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(_ImageBytes));
        }
        return _ImageSource;
    }
```

My initial reaction to this problem was that the converter would be the issue. However, after some investigation and internet research I no longer think this is the case.

After deciding this, I've done some investigation from the perspective of it being a formatting issue within the UWP specific code. As a result of this, I've played around with all parameters I could think would have an effect, and attempted to regenerate the file in various formats to see if this had a positive effect (The thumbnail gets generated as bmp). This also had no success.

At this point I'm pulling my hair out. I cannot figure out why the thumbnails generated from UWP are having an issue being converted to an ImageSource and displayed on iOS. Both UWP and Android have no issues and iOS can display the thumbnails I generate from itself and Android, it's purely the UWP thumbnails it has an issue with. Can someone please help me with this or at least give me some new paths of investigation?